# C# Handling N events asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, message-queue

So the deal is I have a handler listening to a queue, with messages being pushed to it from another service. I know how many messages *should* arrive on the queue, but how can I verify this in a test?

Assuming I have a handler seutp like this:

```
public class Handler<TMessage> : IHandleMessages<TMessage>
{
    public TMessage Message { get; private set; }

    public async Task Handle(TMessage message)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Message = message;
            })
            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }
}
```

So that whenever `TMessage` is put on the queue, it gets consumed.

Now I want something to verify that I indeed receive the number of messages I expect, I have attempted the following:

```
public async Task VerifyReceivedMessages()
{
    //I'm expecting 5 files (how and why is not relevant in this case)
    const int numberOfMessages = 5;
    int numberOfReceivedMessages = 0;

    var receivedMessages = new List<TMessage>();

    var handler = new Handler<TMessage>(new List<TMessage>());

    while (numberOfReceivedMessages < numberOfMessages)
    {
        handler.WaitForMessage();
        foreach (var message in handler.MessageList)
        {
            if (!receivedMessages.Contains(message))
            {
                receivedMessages.Add(message);
                numberOfReceivedMessages = receivedMessages.Count;
            }
        }
    }
    //I rarely get to this one before the program terminates.
    await SaveReceivedMessages(receivedMessages);
}
```

For this to work, I have expanded the handler as well, so it now includes a method for waiting for messages as well as a list of messages, which it adds to whenever it receives one:

```
public class Handler<TMessage> : IHandleMessages<TMessage>
{
    public TMessage Message { get; private set; }
    public List<TMessage> MessageList { get; set; }

    public Handler(List<TMessage> messageList)
    {
        MessageList = messageList;
    }

    public async Task Handle(TMessage message)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Message = message;
                ReceivedMessages(Message);
            })
            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }

    private void ReceivedMessages(TMessage Message)
    {
        MessageList.Add(message);
    }

    public void WaitForMessage(int sleepMsCycle = 100, int sleepLimitMs = 60000)
    {
        long maxWait = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + (sleepLimitMs * 10000);

        while(Message == null && DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks <= maxWait)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleepMsCycle);
        }

        long now = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
        if (now > maxWait)
        {
            //Some exception handling...
        }
    }
}
```

The handler itself seems to work. Whenever the publishing service sends a message, the handler picks it up. The thing is, the publisher can send the 5 messages at varying time intervals, sometimes it's very quick, sometimes it might take a few seconds.

As it is right now, I can't figure out a good way to pick up the messages in `VerifyReceivedMessages()`. The current solution sometimes picks up only 1, 2 or 3 (at seemingly, to me, random), leaving the remaining messages queued up on the queue before terminating at the next iteration of the `foreach`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out [TPL Dataflow](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2016/05/23/tpl-dataflow/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the chance to sleep on this, and turns out the reason it didn't work was because I was trying to read from a list, which was also potentially accessed by the handler during the same time in the `foreach`. Adding `.ToList()` works, but even better, making it into a thread-safe list also solves it.

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<TMessage, string> MessageList { get; set; }

public Handler(ConcurrentDictionary<TMessage, string> messageList)
{
    MessageList = messageList;
}

...

private void ReceivedMessages(TMessage Message)
{
    MessageList.TryAdd(message, "");
}
```